# How to allow access to all objects except for objects in specific wildcard subdirectory?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli

When using following IAM policy, why can I sync objects such as `s3://foo/1/bar/2.pdf` and `s3://foo/3/bar/4.pdf` using [AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/)?

My understanding is that `StringNotLike` should prevent that but when I run `aws s3 sync s3://foo foo/`, objects in `bar` subdirectories are synced.

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::foo",
                "arn:aws:s3:::foo/*",
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": "*/bar/*"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```